# HighCharts pie chart in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, highcharts, pie-chart

I'm trying to display the January sales of products.

Here is the code in my products_controller.

```
@hi = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.options[:chart][:defaultSeriesType] = "pie"
      f.options[:title][:text] = "Jan Sales"

      @products.each do |p|
        f.series(:name=>"Jan Sales", :data=>[:name=> p.title, :y=>p.jan])
      end 
end
```

I get this output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEIAn.png

It displays all of the name of the products (p.title) in the chart legend, however it only displays 1 value of the product's jan sales (p.jan).

Im using lazy high charts gem https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts

Comment: Please provide Highcahrt code and fiddle if possible

Comment: I'm using this gem https://github.com/michelson/lazy_high_charts

Comment: What does ur data object look like when the loop is done?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by data object. Products just have a title, price, and jan to dec sale totals. edit: im new to rails and learning